# How to disable LED on Acer ED270UP Monitor

Tags: display, acer

How can I disable the blue LED on the bottom of my Acer ED270UP Monitor? I’ve checked the settings but can’t seem to find any option. I also want to avoid using tape. Thanks.

Comment: I have found something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/Scotch-Heat-Resistant-Listed-Certified-Electrical/dp/B001AXD0EY/ref=asc_df_B001AXD0EY/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=198088319012&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=11724980925190669255&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=2840&hvtargid=pla-341088702935&psc=1) does wonders.

Comment: The only option other than tape is opening the monitor and physically disabling the LED. You do not want that.

Comment: If you're really set against tape, you could 3D print a cover in the same colour as your monitor. But that's a lot of extra work for a simple problem.

Comment: I took a quick look at a online manual for your model of monitor and it appears the LED is used as a indicator when troubleshooting a defective monitor. So it appears there is no software based method to disable the LED and your only course of action is to follow one of the many hacks in the answers here.

Comment: @DanielB that's clearly not true - black paint is an option I've used on over-bright LEDs, both with and without opening things up

Comment: Have you seen if it is possible to set it via software (In the manual it is stated that  _DDC/CI allows the monitor settings to be set through the software on the pc_)?

Comment: there's a lot of advice for tape, but the real winner I've found is tape + a little aluminum foil

Answer (score 27):

Put a piece of non-transparent tape on it.

Works on all kinds of hardware!

Comment: I even have a selection of different coloured tape, for a multitude of otherwise irritating LEDs around the house ;)

Comment: I've edited my post. I want to avoid using tape, but I appreciate your suggestion nonetheless.

Comment: I'm three feet from five things that have tape over their lights. My 4k ASUS has that option. On an Acer? GL.

Comment: @Tetsujin do you, like me, sometimes choose tape that will act as a dimmer rather than a complete block?

Comment: @ChrisH - Indeed I do. I have some off-white tape which needs probably 5 layers to completely block a bright LED, so usually two or three are used, so I can still see the indicators, without announcing to passing aircraft this might be a good place to land;)

Comment: @Tetsujin working in optics labs I've tried all that sort of thing (brown insulation tape is a quick and dirty solution).  I've even bought offcuts of illegal 90% blocking car window tinting film to cover the entire display of some equipment.

Answer (score 12):

Color the LED with black permanent marker. The ink will not be completely opaque, but will dramatically reduce the brightness of the LED. Easily wiped off with isopropanol if you dislike the result.

Comment: Acrylic markers have much better coverage than the usual alcohol-based permanent markers. On the other hand they are more difficult to remove (again isopropanol, ethanol, ammonia etc.) --- I have a good experience with Pilot Pintor markers: https://www.pilot-pintor.eu/en-en/

Comment: The solvent in permanent markers can possibly scar the plastic around the led permanently, though.

Answer (score 9):

I know you don't want tape.  Use a blob of blu-tack.  Lead a simple life and save brain cells for the things that matter.

Answer (score 7):

To do this without using tape (or blu-tack etc) you might have to do one of the following ...

- open the case and

  - cut one leg of the LED using small side-cutters. [image: cutters and LED]
  - desolder the LED with a soldering iron and flux and solder-wick [image: desoldering tools]
  - crush the LED with needle-nosed pliers [image: crusher]
- get your electric drill out and hope your destruction doesn't penetrate the PCB and that any LED fragments that fall inside are non-conducting or do not land anywhere they will cause a house-enveloping fire.

Frankly a small piece of tape is a better solution. For things where cosmetics matter I sometimes use small round stick-on paper disks of the sort that used to be used on wall-calendars/planning charts

[image: phone with camera covered by round sticker]

For really bright LEDs you might need to epoxy on a small disk of aluminium foil cut using a hole punch.

Comment: If you're going to use a soldering iron anyway, you could also replace the LED with one of a less obnoxious colour, and/or bodge a series resistor in there to reduce the brightness...

Comment: Thanks. I've took the LED out. Much better than covering it in tape!

Comment: @RyderCragie `I've took the LED out.` Great! [page 19 of the manual for you monitor (not sure if it is real or not)](https://www.manualowl.com/m/Acer%20Computers/ED270UP/Manual/637544?page=29#manual) (but most of the time these are status LEDs) says that the LED is used for trouble-shooting!

Comment: Covering the LED with tape BELOW the cover would have been an option...